# What uses / respects the .node-version file?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I've searched Stack Overflow and GitHub (for both node and nvm) for an answer, but to no avail.

In some repos ([like GitHub's Atom text editor](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/.node-version), for instance), I've come across a `.node-version` file. It seems to be analogous to the `.ruby-version` standard file that works with any Ruby version manager to set the current version of Ruby correctly for the project.

[But as far as I can tell from its documentation](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage), nvm (Node Version Manager) only respects a `.nvmrc` file - it mentions nothing about a more general `.node-version` file. And there's no mention of `.node-version` in node's documentation (and I wouldn't expect there to be, since it doesn't ship with a version manager out of the box). I'm not aware of any other node version manager in heavy use.

So my question is, what is `.node-version`? What tools actually use it? Is it just an alias for `.nvmrc`, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are a few version managers for node.js respecting `.node-version` file:

- [avn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/avn) - Automatic Node Version Switching
- [nodenv](https://github.com/OiNutter/nodenv) - Yet another version managers
- [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) - Extendable version manager with support for Ruby, Node.js, Elixir, Erlang & more, provided you [configure it accordingly](https://asdf-vm.com/#/core-configuration?id=tool-versions)
- [nvs](https://github.com/jasongin/nvs) - Node Version Switcher

There may be some other version managers, but I'm not aware of them.

I don't know which particular version manager Atom uses. [nodenv](https://github.com/OiNutter/nodenv) have more stars on GitHub, but [avn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/avn) looks more mature and better maintained for me, not to mention its compatibility with both [n](https://github.com/tj/n) and [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Comment: [ndenv](https://github.com/riywo/ndenv) also uses `.node-version` file.

Comment: I recommend `nodenv` - it also works like `rbenv` and `pyenv` so you can carry over your knowledge.

Comment: Well, the answer might be shorter if explained what does not support `.node-version` file then! All "node version managers" known seem to support it. From what I understand, one could safely assume they can rename their `.nvmrc` file to `.node-version` safely, which would cover more "node version managers". - WELL it seems I misunderstood that answer and `nvm` doesn't support `.node-version`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29545541/2391795

Comment: [nodeenv](https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv)—a node virtual env manager—also uses the file: https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv/blob/0f9e2e2d85240d263016347802453ffec5d64727/nodeenv.py#L138-L140 (note the double "ee" in its name, this is different from [nodenv](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv) linked in the answer, which has a single "e").

Comment: There are lots of version managers now that support `.node-version`. I added a more up to date list in separate answer.

Answer (score 57):

`.node-version` is a file read by various tools on an individual basis for specifying the target node version. Version managers which use/respect it include (in alphabetical order):

- [asdf-nodejs](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs) Node.js plugin for asdf version manager. (macOS, Linux)
- [avn](https://github.com/wbyoung/avn) Automatic Version Switching for Node. (macOS, Linux)
- [chnode](https://github.com/tkareine/chnode) Changes shell's current Node.js version by updating $PATH (macOS, Linux)
- [dev](https://docs.pkgx.sh/using-dev/dev) `dev` is built on [pkgx](https://docs.pkgx.sh), a single, standalone binary that can run anything (macOS, Linux)
- [direnv](https://github.com/direnv/direnv) unclutter your .profile. (macOS, Linux)
- [fnm](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm)  Fast and simple Node.js version manager, built in Rust. (macOS, Linux, Windows)
- [mise](https://github.com/jdx/mise) Polyglot switcher compatible with asdf plugins, built in Rust. (macOS, Linux)
- [n](https://github.com/tj/n) Interactively Manage Your Node.js Versions. (macOS, Linux)
- [nenv](https://github.com/ryuone/nenv) Groom your app’s Node environment with nenv (macOS, Linux)
- [nodeenv](http://ekalinin.github.io/nodeenv/) Virtual environment for Node.js & integrator with virtualenv (macOS, Linux, Windows)
- [nodenv](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv) Manage multiple NodeJS versions. (macOS, Linux)
- [nodist](https://github.com/nullivex/nodist) Natural node.js and npm version manager for windows. (Windows)
- [nve](https://github.com/ehmicky/nve) Run any command on specific Node.js versions (macOS, Linux, Windows)
- [nvm-rust](https://github.com/BeeeQueue/nvm-rust) A cross-platform node version manager that doesn't suck (macOS, Linux, Windows)
- [nvm.fish](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/nvm.fish) Node.js version manager lovingly made for Fish. (macOS, Linux)
- [nvs](https://github.com/jasongin/nvs) Node Version Switcher - A cross-platform tool for switching between versions and forks of Node.js. (macOS, Linux, Windows)
- [setup-node](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) ([configuration](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#node-version-file)) Set up your GitHub Actions workflow with a specific version of node.js

Other products which test for .node-version include:

- [bitrise](https://bitrise.io) The CI/CD Platform built for Mobile DevOps
- [Cloudflare Pages](https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/platform/language-support-and-tools/#supported-languages-and-tools) Build fast sites. In record time.
- [Hostman](https://hostman.com) Hosting platform that deploys your web applications
- [netlify](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/#node-js-and-javascript) Instantly build and deploy your sites to our global network from Git.
- [paketo](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/nodejs/) Your app,
  in your favorite language,
  ready to run in the cloud
- [preferred-node-version](https://github.com/ehmicky/preferred-node-version) Get the preferred Node.js version of a project or user
- [render](https://render.com/docs/node-version) A Cloud for the New Decade
- [Spaceship](https://spaceship-prompt.sh/sections/node/) Minimalistic, powerful and extremely customizable Zsh prompt
- [starship](https://starship.rs/config/#nodejs) ☄️ The minimal, blazing-fast, and infinitely customizable prompt for any shell!
- [Vercel Conformance](https://vercel.com/docs/workflow-collaboration/conformance/rules/REQUIRE_NODE_VERSION_FILE) Conformance provides tools that run automated checks on your code for product critical issues, such as performance, security, and code health.
- [VMware Tanzu](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tanzu-Buildpacks/services/tanzu-buildpacks/GUID-nodejs-nodejs-buildpack.html) The Tanzu Node.js Buildpack supports several popular configurations for Node.js apps.

Note: `nvm` does *not* support reading a `.node-version` file.

I documented usage and some supported features here: https://github.com/shadowspawn/node-version-usage

Answer (score 42):

(disclosure: I maintain http://nvm.sh)

The most-used version managers for node are without a doubt [`nvm`](http://nvm.sh), [`nave`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nave), and [`n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n).

`nvm` is for modifying individual shell sessions to use the version you want.
`nave` is for launching subshells with the version you want loaded.
`n` is for switching a single system-wide version of node.

`nvm` uses a `.nvmrc` file, which like `.ruby-version`, contains the version-ish string X you'd normally couple with `nvm use X` or `nvm install X`. `nvm use` or `nvm install` by itself will locate the `.nvmrc` file, as will simply sourcing `nvm` upon opening a new shell.

It appears `nave` supports a `.naverc` file, but I'm not too familiar with its usage.

`n` doesn't appear to support any such config, but as it's system-wide, it doesn't really make as much sense to do so.

---

`avn` supports `.node-version` and attempts to provide automatic version switching by hooking into `cd`, after `nvm` decided that was too invasive a behavior to include.

Comment: How do you get changing a directory to switch to the .nvmrc just like rvm does?

Comment: You don't, not automatically. `nvm` isn't intrusive like `rvm` is.

You could certainly overwrite your builtin `cd` to run `nvm use`, but how often are you cding around as opposed to using multiple shell tabs?

Comment: It's nice to not have to remember to set your node version when you cd into a project. Nothing worse than killing hours trying to figure out why your app suddenly doesn't work when all this time you forgot to change your node version to the version the app your working on is known to run on. This lack of support for auto switching has me contemplating switching from nvm to avn.

Comment: "auto switching" is intrusive and slow. If you'd like to use it, you can overwrite `cd` yourself, or you can use nvm via avn which does that for you.

Comment: Is there any link to the discussion where auto switching was rejected? Would be interested to learn more about this decision.

Comment: @LJHarb auto switching is not intrusive and slow, there are tools that don't get it right, but it's certainly possible to do it right, take a look into the multiple runtime version manager, `asdf`.

Comment: @goetzc I've used asdf; hijacking `cd` always introduces a slowdown, and using always-pathed shims introduces a slowdown when invoking the tool itself. There's no "right" way to do it that avoids these tradeoffs.

Comment: @LJHarb Could you please clarify whether `nvm` supports `.node-version` file? Or does it only support `.nvmrc`? (the accepted answer is confusing me, and your answer isn't straight-to-the-point)

Comment: @Vadorequest nvm only supports `.nvmrc`.

Comment: rtx supports autoswitching (though technically not on "cd"—that's the wrong place to put it) and thanks to being written in rust the performance impact is negligible. You're not going to notice <5ms of overhead.

Comment: @LJHarb can `nvm` support `.node-version` as a fallback if no `.nvmrc` available, to make our life better?

Comment: @WayneMao you can read all the arguments in either direction on the issue https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/794

Comment: @LJHarb I knew I'm not the first guy. I think I understand your stand after read through that topic. To clearify, I come from [GitHub Action TypeScript Template](https://github.com/actions/typescript-action?tab=readme-ov-file#initial-setup) and in the README it mentions that `nvm` supports `.node-version` (now it looks like a mistake). After I tried but failed, then Google leads me here. My pain is just I have to leave both `.node-version` and `.nvmrc` in my project. I'm ok with this since it is clear now. I love using `nvm` at all, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 6):

[asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) with [asdf-nodejs](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs) supports `.node-version` with

```
legacy_version_file = yes
```

added to `~/.asdfrc`

Answer (score 5):

[Direnv](https://direnv.net/) supports both `.node-version` and `.nvmrc` files. [Direnv](https://direnv.net/) is all I use for loading project-specific versions of Node.js.

https://github.com/direnv/direnv/wiki/node#load-nodejs-version-from-a-node-version-or-nvmrc-file

Answer (score 3):

Using `nvm use` or `nvm install` with no version, nvm will crawl up the file tree looking for a version within a `.nvmrc` file, usually landing at `stable` in `~/.nvmrc`.

Here is a rough 6-line git patch that will look for a local `.node-version` file if no `.nvmrc` file is found:

```
~/.nvm/nvm.sh, ≈line 280
1 file changed, 8 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

# Obtain nvm version from rc file
nvm_rc_version() {
   local NVMRC_PATH
   NVMRC_PATH="$(nvm_find_nvmrc)"
   if [ ! -e "${NVMRC_PATH}" ]; then
-    nvm_err "No .nvmrc file found"
-    return 1
+    local LOCAL_NODE_VERSION_DOTFILE_PATH
+    LOCAL_NODE_VERSION_DOTFILE_PATH="${PWD}/.node-version"
+    if [ -e "${LOCAL_NODE_VERSION_DOTFILE_PATH}" ]; then
+      NVMRC_PATH="${LOCAL_NODE_VERSION_DOTFILE_PATH}"
+    else
+      nvm_err "No .nvmrc file found"
+      return 1
+    fi
```

No cd-hooking, no extra packages to install, just (what I find to be) a sensible default.

Answer (score 3):

fnm also supports .node-version 
https://github.com/fisherman/fnm/

```
for f in .fnmrc .nvmrc .node-version
```